# ValueError sin suficientes valores para desempacar

Tags: python, variables

Haciendo un ejercicio de validacion externa con cross validation y split, con el siguiente código

```
'import pandas as pd
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn import linear_model
 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

 data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/base_datos_2008.csv')

 df = data.dropna(subset = ['ArrDelay'])
 df = df.sample(frac=1).head(1000)

 X = df[['AirTime', 'Distance', 'DepDelay']]
 Y = df['ArrDelay']

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split("X,Y", test_size = .2, random_state = 2)

 regrINTERNA = linear_model.LinearRegression()
 regrINTERNA.fit(X, Y)
 prediccionesINTERNA = regrINTERNA.predict(X)
 print("R2: ", r2_score(Y, prediccionesINTERNA))'
```

Teniendo el siguiente resultado:

```
'X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split("X,Y", test_size = .2, random_state = 2)
 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)'
```

No se cual ea el erro tengo python 3.8.3 de 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Observa como estás pasando **X** y **Y** a train_test_split():

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split("X,Y", test_size = .2, random_state = 2)
```

Estás mandando entre " " comillas dobles tanto X como Y, entonces lo conviertes en una cadena.. así que lo solucionas solo quitándolas y mandando ahora si **X** y **Y** sobre su propio parámetro y valor

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=.2, random_state=2)
```

Comment: Te debo una Caguama (cerveza de 1 lt) por fin pude.